# Using HTTPS in the paypal IPN listener

Tags: security, paypal, paypal-ipn

We are integrating our online payment system with the paypal IPN transaction notification backend and we got stucked with a problem while testing it with the sandbox:

When using the listener script URL with HTTP it works flawlessly, but when specifying a secure URL it stops working. On the IPN history page (https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history) all calls made using the secure listener show no HTTP response from our server(!).
Direct access to both URL work from a browser.

Our guess is that either IPN calls don't work against secure listeners (we couldn't find a word about this in the documentation) or paypal sandbox IPN servers don't like our IPN listener certificate (which is a free startssl but valid certificate).

Did anyone find something similar or Could provide some advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done it with HTTPS, so it does work. You have to put 'https' in the IPN URL of course that's registered at PayPal. Check that your SSL certificate is signed by a recognised CA.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Now the remaining issue is whether the Paypal Sandbox Servers and Production Servers that perform these IPN calls recognise the same set of CAs or they have the Production ones more updated... (startSSL IS a valid CA but it is true that only recently major browsers have stopped complaining about startSSL certs by default)